# Access violation when initializing a D3DBuffer

Tags: c++11, graphics, directx-11

I'm trying to load an obj file full of vertices and render it as a point cloud.
when I try to run my code it crashes and gives me the following error:
Unhandled exception at 0x66463E50 (nvwgf2um.dll) in Tutorial06.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00E9D000.

I followed the tutorial code Microsoft provide with DirectX and changed it to suite my layout and everything but I must have done something wrong and I'm not sure what it is.
This is how I try to initialize my buffer:

```
CloudLoader::getInstance().loadCloudData("cloud.obj");
std::vector<CloudVertex>* data = CloudLoader::getInstance().getCloudData();


D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( CloudVertex ) * data->size();
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = data;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
```

And this my cloud loading code:

```
void CloudLoader::loadCloudData(std::string fileName)
{
    if (m_loaded == false){
        m_loadedData = new std::vector<CloudVertex>();
        std::wifstream fileIn(fileName.c_str());    //Open file
        wchar_t checkChar;
        if (fileIn){
            while (fileIn){
                checkChar = fileIn.get();   //Get next char

                switch (checkChar){
                case 'v':
                    checkChar = fileIn.get();
                    if (checkChar == ' ')   //v - vert position
                    {
                        float vz, vy, vx;
                        fileIn >> vx >> vy >> vz;   //Store the next three types
                        m_loadedData->push_back(CloudVertex(vx, vy, vz));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    m_loaded = true;
}
```

I guess its a C++ thing and not directX and its probably really simple but I've been stuck on this for a while now, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I forgot to mention but my data includes around 50K vertices

Answer (score 0):

pSysMem cannot point at "data", as this is a pointer to the std::vector class and not actually the data contained within the vector.

Try:

```
InitData.pSysMem = data->data();
```